# How do I prevent screen dimming for specific apps?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, screen

My phone has Android 4.0.4 (ICS). Now, I use several apps for reading like browser, Wikipedia, Adobe Reader, etc. Only Adobe has a screen dimmer setting.

Is there an app or setting that allows me to stop the screen from turning off while I have any of these apps open for reading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's one of the many things [Tasker](http://www.appbrain.com/app/tasker/net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) does for me, with a quite simple profile:

- **Condition:** App (select your browser, reader, etc., multiple apps can be selected simultaneously)
- **Task:** Display-Timeout (all sliders to max = never)

Optionally, you also can adjust screen brightness. Then, as soon as one of the selected apps is running in the foreground, that action triggers – the screen won't turn off anymore. When you bring another app in front which was not selected with your condition, *Tasker* reverts to the previous state automatically.

Of course, there are also several apps available just doing that and nothing else; but having one app ([tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker)) that can doing this and so much more, I forgot about them long ago...

Answer (score 0):

Found this while searching for info on how to prevent screen dimming in KOReader. In KOReader in top settings > Settings (Cogwheel icon) > Screen > with `Automatic Dimmer` enabled it is possible to set `Idle time for dimmer` to a custom value.

Disabling `Automatic Dimmer` did not result in the screen not dimming, since it seems KOReader then was following general system settings for which I wanted to keep screen dimming.