# I just got a (used) Nexus 7 (2013).... And it goes to standby too quickly too often

Tags: nexus-7, standby

Is there are a way to configure it, with an app or guide, to be able to READ "something really interesting" in this tablet without the screen constantly randomly going off too soon?

I would understand that the tablet had something that told the system to keep being awake while I'm using "apps" that are obviously for "reading"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The screen doesn't *randomly* turn off: it turns off after a fixed time. You can change how long before the screen turns off in the main device settings: **Display** → **Sleep**. This applies regardless of what app is in the foreground.

If you like, you can use a third-party automation tool such as Tasker or Llama to change the screen timeout according to what app you're using. [This question explains how.](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/57984/12442)

Samsung phones also have a feature called "Smart stay". This activates the front-facing camera just before it turns the screen off, to check whether you're looking at the screen: if so, it leaves the screen on for a while longer. This isn't a standard Android feature: it was developed by Samsung and only available on their phones.

Comment: Do you know any alternative to Samsung's?

Comment: No. As I said, the feature is only available on their phones.

Comment: Hey Dan, I haven't test it yet though: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.beansoft.eyespy.free